# Можно ли в цитате изменять орфографию?

Tags: орфография, цитата, редактура

Например, цитата из Евангелия, где, как известно, не используется буквы ё. Но в тексте, куда эта цитата помещается, везде обязательно проставлять букву ё. Возможны ли вообще такие изменения ради единообразия орфографии текста, даже если отвлечься от буквы ё (например, это могут быть случаи с прописной и строчной буквой, случаи, вроде двояких написаний: по всему тексту *диавол*, а в цитате *дьявол*, или *Божиего* и *Божьего*)? Причём с автором цитаты никто не будет связываться. Или, допустим, цитата взята из текста с какого-то сайта.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В "Справочнике издателя и автора" А.Мильчина сказано следующее:

> Цитата должна слово в слово, буква в букву, знак препинания в знак
>   препинания следовать источнику, за некоторыми исключениями — см. ниже,
>   8.1.6—8.1.9.

Ниже выдержки из 8.1.6. "Орфография и пунктуация в цитатах". Подробнее можно ознакомиться [по этой ссылке](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL03/70091470.html).

> Текст цитаты, как правило, приводится в соответствии с правилами и
>   нормами орфографии и пунктуации, действующими в момент издания.
>
> Исключения:
>
> 1. Сохраняют инд. особенности орфографии и пунктуации
>      автора, написания слов, характерные для стиля автора и эпохи.
> 2. Не исправляют опечатки и ошибки в цитатах из произведений печати, современных выпускаемому изданию, помещая после неверно написанного
>      слова (словосочетания) вопросительный знак в круглых скобках или
>      правильно написанное слово (словосочетание) в прямых скобках.
>
> Допустимо также исправлять явные опечатки при условии, что исправление
>   оговаривается в примечании, но это целесообразно делать лишь в
>   случаях, когда цитирующему надо прокомментировать ошибку в цитате.

Answer (score 1):

С изменениями в орфографии меняется подлинный смысл (понятия  сакральные одним движением могут превратиться в обыденные, светские). Изменения могут касаться лишь объёма цитируемых фрагментов текста: они могут содержать начало, окончание или фразу с опущенной срединной частью при безусловном сохранении содержания.

В определённых случаях можно прибегать к сноскам для подачи использованных фрагментов (отдельных слов) в подлинной орфографии и ссылками на источник.